# Instanced Branch Bending

Tags: geometry-nodes, instances

This questions is an expansion of this one.
[Vector rotation of branches on curve with rotation](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/271357/vector-rotation-of-branches-on-curve-with-rotation/271365?noredirect=1#comment464912_271365)

The solution to falls apart as soon as you add a layer of instances - branches on branches.  I cannot find a way to curl branches up/down along the trunks.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the answer - but would love to know if there's a 'simpler' way as well as some explanation of why the first realize instances node is required.[image]

[image]